# Nested destructuring doesn't work in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, destructuring

So i have done some restful routing in my react app and want to access the parameters.

And this does work:

```
const TreeList = ( props ) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{`Trees filterd by ${props.match.params.searchBy}, with the key of ${props.match.params.key}.`}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

So does this:

```
const TreeList = ( {match} ) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{`Trees filterd by ${match.params.searchBy}, with the key of ${match.params.key}.`}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

But when I tried to destructure it further, I came across JS nested destructuring, which should look like this:

```
const TreeList = ( {match: {params}} ) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>TreeList</h1>
            <p>{`Trees filterd by ${params.searchBy}, with the key of ${params.key}.`}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

But it doesn't work. :(

Comment: It would just be `${params.searchBy}`; otherwise, what's the point of the further desctructuring?

Comment: oh I'm sorry, I wrote that wrong in the question, I did have 'params.searchBy' in the template string, the error occurs at the '{match: {params}}

Comment: What error occurs??

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-gwen-45hg8?file=/src/index.js seems to work just fine. What is not working exactly?

Comment: huh now it does, just wrote it down. I was having a weird errot before, that "match" would not be known or semthing like that.
But seemingly the same thing works now, thanks :)